# mvc pop up window

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, popup

I have an mvc project with a jqgrid that has an editting column, my problem is when i Try to link the edit in each row to a pop up window, when I add the code below a window pop up opens but I recieve a 402 unothorized error, here is my code in the controller

```
var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,

            rows = (
              from item in items

              select new
              {
                  id = item.Id,
                  cell = new string[] { 
                    "<A HREF=javascript: void(0)  onclick=window.open

                 ('/Views/viewname/Edit/'+"item.code+",'Edit','width=700,height=800'); >Edit</A>",

                            column2,
                           column3,
                           etc ...}
              }).ToArray()
        };
```

but if I just link the edit to a regular page through this code

```
var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,

            rows = (
              from item in items


              select new
              {
                  id = item.Id,
                  cell = new string[] { 
                    "<a href=viewfolder/Edit/"+item.Code +">Edit</a> "  ,
                            column2,
                           column3,
                           etc ...}
              }).ToArray()
```

I do not have any problems, I have a edit page which works fine if it is not a pop up window, has anybody faced this problem, or can anyone direct me to an example that is similar.Thnaks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried with quotes around your `href` and `onclick` attribute values?